# Where and when should I use the close() method to avoid IOException in ObjectInputStream?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, objectinputstream

I'm trying to read an object from client program over tcp. As you can see in this line I created objectInput:

```
ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(incoming.getInputStream());
```

And then read my input from the other program. It used to work fine until i made minor changes to clean up the program. Personally Assume I added

```
objectInput.clsoe();
```

My question is, After reading the object should I close the objectInputStream or Keep remain without close? Should I close it straight away after using it or at the end of if block or at the end of program? What are the effect of the close? By the way I have read the close documentation.

Here is the error:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2280)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2749)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:779)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:279)
    at Server.ClientWorker.run(MyCollectionServer.java:116)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try 
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);  
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
                {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(true)
        {   
            ClientWorker w;
            try
            {   
                w = new ClientWorker(serverSocket.accept());
                Thread t = new Thread(w);
                t.start();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }   
        }
    }
}

class ClientWorker implements Runnable
{
.....
    private Socket incoming;
    public ClientWorker(Socket incoming)
    {
        myList = new ArrayList<PureAlbum>();
        loadList();
        this.incoming = incoming;
    }

.....
    public synchronized  void run()
    {

else if(request.compareTo("AddAlbum")==0)
        {
            try
            {
                ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(incoming.getInputStream()); //This is the line mentioned in the error
                PureAlbum object = (PureAlbum) objectInput.readObject();


                if(object instanceof CDAlbum)
                {
                    CDAlbum a = (CDAlbum) object;
                    myList.add(a);
                    System.out.println("Artist = " + a.getArtist());
                }
                else if(object instanceof Client.au.edu.uow.Collection.DVDAlbum)
                {
                    myList.add((DVDAlbum) object);              
                }
                else
                {
                    System.err.println("Warning : The object to add to database is unknown! "+ object.getClass() + "*");
                    System.exit(0);
                }


            }
            catch (UnknownHostException e) 
            {
                System.err.println("Can not read the host name");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.err.println("Can not read the FILE name"); //This exception has been called
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: If on Java 7, use Automatic Resource Management. If not, use a `finally` block to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of stack trace shows that the exception is occurring when you are initializing the `ObjectInputStream`, not when you are closing.

```
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:279)
```

The most likely cause is that the remote client did not open an `ObjectOutputStream`.  It might have written some other kind of data, or it might have closed its output stream or simply exited.

Comment: Close. I think he is opening a new `ObjectInputStream` per message, and not finding the correct stream header, etc, as the peer didn't open a new corresponding `ObjectOutputStream`. It's the old use-the-same-streams-for-the-life-of-the-connection game.

Comment: the problem was I was sending a message "add" to the server and after that sending the object to add to the database in the sever. and in object side first I read the "add" message which is cool but I read the object which haven't sent yet and to avoid this I added Thread.sleep(1000); to the client side after sending the message "ADD"....Anyway thanks for your reply

Comment: @Bernard Adding sleeps to networking code is just cargo-cult programming. Possibly you needed to flush your output stream.

Answer (score 5):

Your code fragment is pretty long, so I will try to give you a general answer and it will hopefully help you.

The typical patterns of usage of `stream.close()` prior to java 7 are:

```
InputStream in = null; 
try {
    InputStream in = .....; // create your input stream;
    // use input stream
} catch (IOException e) {
    // do what you need here
} finally {
    if (in != null) {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

or simply declare the method as `throws IOException` and then write:

```
InputStream in = null; 
try {
    InputStream in = .....; // create your input stream;
    // use input stream
} finally {
    if (in != null) {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Pay atention that this example does not contain `catch` section.

Starting from java 7 we can enjoy the new facilities of the language:

```
try (
    InputStream in = .....; // create your input stream;
) {
    // use input stream
}
```

You even do not have to call `close()` at all. All resources defined into header of try block that implement interface `Closable` will be closed automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. it seems to me the error is not because of close. Because when it reaches to 
ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(incoming.getInputStream());
it gets the error.

Answer (score 1):

You should close the Stream when you have completed your reading or writing.
here in this case , you should close the InputStream when you have read the file completely and you no longer require to read file from stream.

In Short , You should close the Stream when its work is over.
It may be in the end of program or after if loop....depends on your use case.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it this way (different example):

```
private void readFile() throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    Object aux = null;

    try {

        fis = new FileInputStream("lib.dat");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        do {
            aux = ois.readObject();
            if (aux instanceof MyObject)
                this.myObjectInstance.add((MyObject) aux);
        } while (true);

    } catch (EOFException e) {
        ois.close();
    }
}
```

This way I am sending any relevant "Error" Exception upstairs to be handled, and once the EndOfFileException is launched this is specifically captured to close the stream properly.

The object has to be defined outside the Try block to be accessible from the Catch block.

The close() method could as well throw an IOException and this can't be caught by our Try block, this would have to be passed by the generic "throw Exception" of readFile() method.